# Question on Perfect Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I'm supposed to prove the following,

> $n$ is an even perfect number if and only if $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ where $(2^p-1)$ and $p$ are prime.

My proof:

Suppose $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$. Let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $n$. Then,
$$\sigma(n) = \sigma(2^{p-1})\sigma(2^p-1) = (2^p-1)2^p = 2n.$$
For the other direction, suppose $n$ is an even perfect number. Let $n= 2^sj$ where $j$ is an odd integer. We know that
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{2} = \frac{(2^{s+1}-1)\sigma(j)}{2}= n.$$
So,
$$(2^{s+1}-1)\frac{\sigma(j)}{2} = 2^sj.$$
By inspecting the parity of the terms, we see that $j = (2^{s+1}-1)$ and $\sigma(j) = 2^{s+1} = j+1$. Since $j$ has only two divisors, it is prime. Moreover, since $(2^{s+1}-1)$ is prime, clearly $s+1=p$ where $p$ is some prime number ( if not, we would be able to factor $(2^{s+1}-1)$ but that is impossible because it is prime.) Hence,
$$n=2^ej = 2^{p-1}(2^p-1).\square$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It's quite convincing to me. I only have a little doubt on "by inspecting the parity of the terms". Can you elaborate a bit more? :)

Comment: Would it be more convincing to argue as follows: $2^s$ divides the right side so it must divide the left side, but since $(2^{s+1}-1)$ is odd, clearly $2^s$ divides $ \frac{\sigma(j)}{2}$. Similarly, $\frac{\sigma(j)}{2}$ divides both sides, but $j$ is odd so $\frac{\sigma(j)}{2}$ divides $ 2^s$. Since $\frac{\sigma(j)}{2}$ and $2^s$ divide each other, they are equal.

Comment: @BUI Quang-Tu ^

Comment: Why does “$j$ is odd$” imply “$\frac{\sigma(j)}{2}$” divides $2^s$?

Comment: To my opinion, you have to work out the part "inspecting the parity" more clearly.